# How to scrape attributes containing string characters (python, beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all `href` tags that contains `^/album$`. When I print out my result, I get an empty list. I have tried `find()` and `findAll()` with `re.compile` and `re.search`. I am unable to get anything other than an empty list.

Code:

```
vk_urls = soup.find_all('a')
vk_albums = soup.findAll(text='^/album$')
print(vk_albums)
```

Result:

```
[]
```

Desired Result:

```
/album...
/album...
/album...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `href=` instead of `text=` (or `string=` in Beautiful Soup 4) to filter by content of `href` attribute. The latter (i.e. `text` and `string`) are used to search for strings within tags.

To find all anchor tags with an `href` attribute that contains `/album`, you need to do the following:

```
vk_albums = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile("^/album"))
print(vk_albums)
```

You can then loop through this list to print just the `href` attributes:

```
for album in vk_albums:
    print(album['href'])
```

Comment: The result is: `[]`

Comment: Okay, the reason it seems I was getting an empty list was because of `^/album$`. I thought I was supposed to include `$`.

Comment: Now I am getting the entire `<a>` tag. One step closer.